# How to create a layout of listview as below picture in Android?

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android

[image: [Setting layout on android]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oG85d.png)

How to create a layout of listview as the picture.

I want item 1 of listview will show a picture and a few information.
 after item 2, item 3 is normal item listview ( or there are some radio). Thanks

Comment: It's called a PreferenceScreen.  https://developer.xamarin.com/api/type/Android.Preferences.PreferenceScreen/

Comment: Using the image in reperenceScreen? How to do that?

Comment: Yes, that image is a PreferenceScreen. That's up to you to read the documentation and figure out how to implement it. Please come back with a new post about any problems you have doing so.

Comment: There seems to be a sample of this in https://github.com/xamarin/monodroid-samples/tree/master/ApiDemo

Comment: which items do you mean? because none of the items in the picture has picture inside.
But it is easy just create a layout which have 2 textview, and in your adapter when you are binding the item, set text to the second textview if it has information or set its visibility to gone if it doesn't have information.

Answer (score -1):

Please read the following tutorial [implement Android Listview with multiple row layout](http://www.survivingwithandroid.com/2014/08/android-listview-with-multiple-row.html)

Please note you will need to do some modification in the above tutorial to improve the memory usage.

Comment: Please see this question is tagged with Xamarin. Also, links aren't answers, sorry.

Comment: Xamarin is like android native exactly. it is the same idea, you will have two types of data for example Header and details. Header and details will inherit from a base class. the list adapter will contains a list from the base class and then in get view you will decide which view you will display according to the class type. your adapter class will inherit  from BaseAdapter<T>

Comment: Can you please provide a code example in your answer then instead of just a link? Even if you have to copy the revelant sections from it? You can read more about [link only answers](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers)